# Path based routing not working in ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I have a single host name and I want to host two applications based on different paths I want the request to be routed based on the ursl path but it picks up only the first path. And gives me the 404 error when i request for second path URL

I am using nginx ingress controller. Here is my file

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: frontent-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: mycustom-domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: frontent-orion-service
                port:
                  number: 4200
          - path: /grafana
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: grafana
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

When i hit mycustom-domain.com - it is working fine goes to frontend service
but when i hit mycustom-domain.com/grafana it also goes to frontend service and gives me 404

Answer (score -1):

Resolved this by changing the application path of my grafana app points to /grafana

reference link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-psa

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).